# Cordova 3.3 Android and Google maps, Chromium error

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova, chromium

Just I'm trying to have a min example of Google maps working on Cordova Android.
The code works fine on localhost with Chrome and Firefox, but i can't get it work on the device.

Example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            window.addEventListener('deviceready',function(){
                var latitud = xx.xxxxxxx;
                var longitud = x.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
                success(latitud,longitud);
            },true);  

            function success(latitud,longitud) {
                var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitud, longitud);

                var options = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: coords,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                navigationControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
                },
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("prova_maps"), options);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: coords,
                  map: map,
                  title:"You are here!"
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <h1>Google Maps</h1>
        <div id='prova_maps' style='height:250px;width:250px;'></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I have the following error at console that is directly relaunched with that problem, but can't find a solution for that:

https://imageshack.com/i/f3myppp

I have the access tags added in config.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And even try to add

And in index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../platform/js/libs/cordova.js"></script>
```

Try to add this link in the script...tag

> google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

Comment: Just it didn't work for me when I only put the listener